# Conversion of Latitude & Longitude to X & Y coordinates for a given plane with specified reference points

Tags: python

[image: View the image here]

Hi guys, as seen in the picture (click above), the rectangle represents a plane that is specified with reference points at the edges in latitude and longitude. The yellow highlighted represents what I have entered in the code as reference points. I defined the bottom left as x,y (0,0) and top right as (11.75, 13.75) which are the actual dimensions of the plane.

I am interested to find the x,y coordinates of a given set of latitude and longitude represented by the stars relative to x,y (0,0).

The formula I'm currently using is:

```
x = 11.75*(a-a1)/(a2-a1)

y = 13.75*(b-b1)/(b2-b1)
```

where a and b represents longitude and latitude of the stars, and (a1,b1) representing first reference point (bottom left) and (a2,b2) representing second reference point (top right).

However, the formula does not yield the results I'm looking for.

Comment: My first comment would be that I have no idea what you're asking - you mention the formula you're currently using, but not what the issue with it is. Secondly, I'm no math expert but is it even possible to convert the first image to the second? The lat/long coordinates you show result in a shape that I do not believe is rectangular, so I'm not sure how you would convert it into a rectangle.

Comment: Shapely, pyProj, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(geometry)#Describing_a_plane_through_three_points

Comment: Hi, the latitude and longitudes provided in the first image are retrieved from google maps that show a rectangular-shaped building. It has actual dimensions of 13.75 x 11.75 metres. 

There is no conversion involved from the first to second image as they are given reference points. The conversion that I'm interested in is from the third to the forth image. This requires me to convert a list of latitude and longitude (represented in stars) to x and y relative to the bottom left coordinate (0,0).

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a simple linear model problem!

For people who still suffer this problem, see solutions at: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23998/seeking-qgis-affine-equation

To solve this issue in a nice way, use R package `vec2dtransf`, working example here:

```
library(vec2dtransf)
data(control.points)
# see a screenshot of control points below, you need to convert your refernce points to this table
at <- AffineTransformation(control.points[,2:5])
calculateParameters(at)

# your target points here:
x <- c(1172615,1096966)
y <- c(1718170,1748774)
xy <- cbind(x,y)
S <- SpatialPoints(xy)

trS <- applyTransformation(st, S)
trS 
# trS is what you want
```

[image]